# Data not being read by ServerSocket

Tags: java, android, sockets

I'm trying to work on multiple AVD in Android and sending data between them using Sockets.

Serverside code-snippet:

```
ServerSocket ss = new ServerSocket(10000);
Log.v("ReceiverTask", "Receiver waiting for requests");
connectedSocket = ss.accept();
ObjectInputStream ois = new ObjectInputStream(connectedSocket.getInputStream());
Object obj = ois.readObject();
ois.close();
ss.close();
```

Client side code:

```
Socket socket = new Socket(InetAddress.getByAddress(new byte[]{10, 0, 2, 2}),njr.sendTo());
BufferedOutputStream bos = new BufferedOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());
ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(bos);                       
oos.writeObject(njr);
Log.d("Client","Object send successfull");
oos.flush();                    
bos.flush();                    
oos.reset();
oos.close();
bos.close();
socket.close();
```

The problem is that The objects that are sent from one AVD (as given by log) is not being received at other AVD. This happens sometimes and not always at a same point. Any hints as to what could be the problem???

Comment: what are you doing with `njr.sendTo()` ?

Comment: @VedPrakash: njr.sendTo() gives me the destination port to which this (client) socket has to send the object

Comment: Make sure your server socket isn't closed before the data is sent to client. This may be the problem. Check it out.

Comment: @VedPrakash did you mean "Make sure your server socket isn't closed before data is received from client???"

Comment: This is different. It may happen that as soon as the process start sending the data to client the socket gets closed. This happens usually by the exceptions in the sending process. Then you may be thinking that you sent the data. However it has never sent at all. Make sure. Check it again.

Comment: @VedPrakash How to handle such cases?

Comment: well easy. Use try and catch blocks for your code and check for exceptions specifically when you do not get any data.

Answer (score 0):

use `oos.flush()` at the end in client.

```
socket = new Socket(InetAddress.getByAddress(new byte[]{10, 0, 2, 2}),njr.sendTo());
bos = new BufferedOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());
oos = new ObjectOutputStream(bos);                      
oos.writeObject(njr);
oos.flush();
oos.close();
Log.d("Client","Object send successfull");
```

Answer (score 0):

Close the stream after reading, else it will assume that its still open

```
oos.Close();
```

Comment: I did that... I'm closing the streams both on the client side as well as the server side.